# File reading issues in Nokia Asha 303

Tags: java-me, nokia-s40

I am reading a fixed number of characters from a file. The file contains both english and arabic text. I have two devices Nokia X3-02 and Nokia Asha 303 for testing. On Nokia X3-02, I am getting the correct string that I require from the file in every case. But on Asha 303, I do not get the complete string when the string contains some arabic character.

I have also tested my code on the sun emulator and it is working fine on it too. The issue seams to be with Nokia Asha 303 device only.

My code is a very simple one in which I read a file by specifying the reading position (Offset) and the length to be read. Please help me as I do not understand this problem.

Comment: show your code, preferably as [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/ "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example")

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue. On Nokia x3-02 the app was reading the exact number of characters as specified in the read function of InputStreamReader but on Nokia Asha 303, the characters read were always less than the ones specified. So I had to loop the read function in order to read all characters. Now it is working on Nokia Asha 303.